# Что делает знак тильда(~) в css?

Tags: css

Пожалуйста об'ясните по людськи, ато я на других сайтах не понимаю.

Почему не работает:

```
button:hover ~ img {
   margin-left:800px;
   transition:10.0s;
} ?
```

Answer (score 6):

Селектор для `img`, перед которым (в том же родителе) есть `button`, над которым находится мышь.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp

```css
button:hover ~ img {
   margin-left:800px;
   transition:10.0s;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button><span>AAA</span><img src="aaa.jpg" alt="ABCD" />
```

Answer (score 2):

http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/sibling это называется родственные селекторы. Стиль будет применен к картинке которая находится на одном уровне с button и идет после него.

Comment: насчёт "сразу после него" - это вы тут промахнулись)

Comment: @meine да, видимо прочитал так.